# iOS: Facebook Posting Privacy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook

Does anyone know why when I post a status / message to the current authenticated user in my app, the default privacy that appears is "Only Me" in facebook? I've read and tried their API reference including this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ but my app just stop working. Why is this so?

This is my code to post the user's status(pre-generated):

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   appId, @"app_id",
                                   @"Event Invitation", @"name",
                                   @"Event Invitation", @"caption",
                                   eventInvitationText, @"description",
                                   eventInvitationLink, @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   nil];

    [self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Referring to the link, I had also added the:

```
@"EVERYONE", @"privacy"
```

as one of its parameter for privacy but when I add it, the fb dialog will just say that there is an error in my app.

Can you help me guys? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user can choose a maximum visibility setting for your app when authorising it to post on their behalf in the auth dialog.- your app can't choose a privacy setting more open than whatever the user chose there

(Nor can your app prompt them to increase the settings but they can change it themselves in `Privacy Settings` - `Apps, Games & Websites` on their Facebook profile)

Comment: does it mean that it is not possible?

Comment: It means you can't override the user's chosen privacy setting (at least, you can't make anything MORE public than what they've chosen), yes

Comment: I'm doing something similar with the 3.11 SDK, attempting to post something with a privacy of "SELF" when the default audience is "Friends".  So I'm unclear if it's even possible to make a change on a per-post basis?